# I have a BIP39 seed but I cannot successfully recover the wallet on Electrum

Tags: wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed

Saw a photo of a screenshot I took and uploaded to Facebook 8 years ago, the address in the picture was this https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/19ScMXCyxoL1igxuw2LqRCtfdZb5WdQGJC and turns out that wallet still have some coins!

The screenshot came from Bitcoin from Android, or so I believe:

[image: screenshot from 8 years ago]

Today I was able to access an old KeePass password database and I still have backups of some wallets in there:

[image: screenshot of KeePassX unlocked]

I successfully restored the one called "Cartera personal" (in red), sadly is in 0.

But I'm having troubles restoring the other waller, the one which, I believe, has some funds left and is related to the address I linked above: "billetera de calle (telefono android)". I already have the seed store in KeePass, and despite [following the restoration process with Electrum](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-standard-wallet-from-seed/) I see no transactions, like it was a new Bitcoin wallet.

**I'm 100% sure that one wallet is the one in the screenshot, then, what am I doing wrong?**

EDIT: from this Android wallet some transactions were sent and turns out the address were from an exchange to an account I still control, it only have less than a dollar tho.

Comment: How old are the wallets exactly? I had one quite old seed (from 2013 or 2014) and I needed to use an old version of Electrum to recover it.

Comment: 2013 I think, did you follow a guide or something?

Comment: No, I couldn't find any. I could consider revisiting the topic to make one unless you want to try first. What OS are you on? 1.9.8 version is what I would try as 1.9.x was a major release in late 2013: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/releases/tag/1.9.8 it uses python 2.6..

Comment: Well the windows builds are still here. The portable exe is probably the easiest way to proceed if you got a trustworthy windows computer around: https://download.electrum.org/1.9.8/

Comment: I dug out my old seed from 2014, but it's not BIP39, so the information I have provided earlier probably does not apply to your use case. Sorry. My seed appears to be from before electrum started using a word list (it's just a long hexadecimal string).